# why occurred parameter error using std::bind

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, bind

I'm studing c++11 spec.

using std::bind, I don't understand why error occurred.

simple code is below.

```
class ClassInfo
{
public:
    ClassInfo() : nID(0) {}
    ~ClassInfo() {}

    bool GetInfo1(int nVal1, int& nOutVal1, std::string& strOut1, std::string& strOut2 )
    {
        nOutVal1 = nID;
        strOut1 = "out1";
        strOut2 = "out2";
        return true;
    }
    bool GetInfo2(int nVal1, int& nOutVal1, std::string& strOut1, std::string& strOut2, std::string& strOut3 )
    {
        nOutVal1 = nID;
        strOut1 = "out1";
        strOut2 = "out2";
        strOut3 = "out3";
        return true;
    }

    int nID;
};

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<ClassInfo> spInfo = std::make_shared<ClassInfo>();
    spInfo->nID = 10;

    int nVal1 = 5;
    int nOutVal1;
    std::string strOut1;
    std::string strOut2;
    std::string strOut3;

    auto _func1 = std::bind(&ClassInfo::GetInfo1, spInfo, nVal1, std::ref(nOutVal1), std::ref(strOut1), std::ref(strOut2));
    _func1();

    auto _func2 = std::bind(&ClassInfo::GetInfo2, spInfo, nVal1, std::ref(nOutVal1), std::ref(strOut1), std::ref(strOut2), std::ref(strOut3));
    _func2();
}
```

this code is not compile..

```
auto _func1 = std::bind(&ClassInfo::GetInfo1, spInfo, nVal1, std::ref(nOutVal1), std::ref(strOut1), std::ref(strOut2));
```

this is ok but

```
auto _func2 = std::bind(&ClassInfo::GetInfo2, spInfo, nVal1, std::ref(nOutVal1), std::ref(strOut1), std::ref(strOut2), std::ref(strOut3));
```

compile error occurred in this code.
why error occurred?

Comment: please [edit] your question and add the compiler error message

Comment: what kind of compiler error you are getting, for me after including `iostream, string and memory` your code runs perfectly without any compiler error

Comment: looks like bug in your compiler clang/gcc compiles fine your code

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this problem.
this error occurred visual studio 2012.
visual studio 2015 is clear. so I resolved using boost bind